# Encapsulating what doesn't vary?

Tags: java, design-patterns

It's a common practice to encapsulate code that often changes. In fact, it is often in the form of using an object to delegate the varying logic to. A sample would be the following:

```
public class SampleClass {
    Object obj = new ObjectWithVaryingMethod();
    public SampleClass(Object obj){
        this.obj=obj;
    }
    public String getString(){
        return obj.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SampleClass sampleClass=new SampleClass(new ObjectWithVaryingMethod());
        System.out.println(sampleClass.getString());
    }
}

class ObjectWithVaryingMethod{
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

Can you suggest what problems I may encounter when "encapsulation" is done on what doesn't vary? I find it to be a good coding conduct when the main class itself is the one that is often subject to change or improvement. A sample would be the following. In this second case, retrieving "Hi", which is the part that doesn't vary, was "encapsulated" in another class.

```
public class SampleVaryingClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //here I may opt to print getHi's value on sysout or on a dialog
        System.out.println(ObjectWithNonVaryingMethod.getHi());
    }
}
```

In a completely different class...

```
public class ObjectWithNonVaryingMethod {
    private static final String hi = "Hi";
    //"Hi" should always be returned
    public static String getHi() {
        return hi;
    }
}
```

Can you give some pro's and con's on doing this?

Comment: Can you suggest the corresponding design pattern then? An example I can give for this is using a DatePicker object.

Comment: I don't understand the question. May give some examples here?

Comment: @Fendy sure. I edited the question and gave an example to be more specific. Anyway, can a question that is put on hold be answered still?

Comment: Maybe you should have listened to what the instructor said in class.

Comment: I was absent probably. Would you like to give some notes about it if you were present? :D

Comment: Forget about encapsulation -- it's really only a tool employed to further other ends.  Look up "separation of concerns" -- that's the real key to the solution of all complex computer programming problems.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't get how encapsulation "furthers other ends". Care to explain more? I'll check "separation of concerns" out.

Comment: Encapsulation helps with separation of concerns.  Encapsulation helps with security/integrity issues.  But encapsulation for encapsulation's sake is stupid.

Comment: Hi, so some of the uses of encapsulation include separation of concerns and help on integrity issues. Both can be seen on the second code above, so let's count that on the pros. Thanks man. If you have time may you answer also how "encapsulating what varies" can differ from "separating the non-changing code"?

Comment: The point is that those differences have to do with the goals that encapsulation furthers -- not with encapsulation itself.  You have to know the goal to know the difference.

Comment: Hi, if I'm right about your point then you're saying it's alright to encapsulate what doesn't vary as long as there's a goal for it. Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Both code cannot be compared each other. One is static, another one isn't. I hope you understand the concept of encapsulating the object in the first code. Here is the pros and cons for the second one. Remember that static is "generally" bad, and do not support concurrency by default.

pros:

1. With `getHi`, you are keeping the string field private, meaning that it cannot be set from other source
2. Say that you need to do `setHi` from other source, you can add several guard clauses for it. This is called `defensive programming`.

   ```
   public static setHi(String input){
       if(input == null) { input = ""; } // can throw exception instead
       hi = input;
   }
   ```

cons:

1. It is static, needless to say
2. You don't get any advantage other than guard clauses. If your class is not static, you can swap it with other class implementing same interface, or other class inherited from that class.

Comment: Hi Fendy, I'm thinking we can compare them because they both print "Hi". Also, wouldn't making getHi() static be a good idea here instead since all getHi() does is print "Hi" for all calls. This is so that there will be only one copy of "Hi".

Comment: Hi Fendy, would you like to defend your position regarding "static"? I'm just wondering maybe I'm missing something. Your additional comments would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @bimboxX actually it is very easy to search at the web why `static` is considered bad. `Does not support concurrency by default`, `cannot be abstracted with classes / objects`, and `disable you to several design patterns such as decorators` is enough for me to not use static.

Comment: Moreover, discussion about static is another question and out of topic in this question.

Comment: Alright, so using static has its pros and cons which can be translated to the second code's pros and cons. Pros include having only one copy of "Hi" and being able to use defensive programming while the cons include unsupported concurrency by default, the limitation of not being able to inherit, and the constraint of not being able to use several design patterns such as decorators. Thank you! So far, the use of static and encapsulation have been the factors in determining the difference between separating what varies and separating what doesn't vary. Any more?

Comment: FYI, non-static can also use defensive programming. Regarding to vary, I cannot give any advise, since the terms "Vary" is not widely used, so I don't know what kind of unit is "vary" or not.

Comment: I see. So defensive programming depended on the encapsulation of "Hi" and not on the use of static? When I said "encapsulate what varies" I meant "encapsulate the code that often changes". Doing this is an OOP principle.